# How to determine if a node.js requests library error is an ssl/tls error, or if it is caused by something else?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request, node-request

I'm interested in detecting certain groups of errors that might be triggered by a requests call like

```
request(someUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    // ...
});
```

I know that I can check the `error.code` value for particular values like `error.code === 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED'`, `error.code === 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'`, or `error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'`

I'm interested in branching on the general type of an error. In my particular use case, I want to detect any kind of ssl such as the cert errors in the examples above. Is there some way to check if an error is in a particular logical grouping of errors? I'm imagining something like

```
if (error instanceof SSLError) {
   // ...
} else {
   // ...
}
```

For instance, in the python requests library, one might catch a `ConnectionError` exception and handle that differently than a `ConnectTimeout` exception. Is there an analogous pattern that can be used in node/node requests that is more elegant than checking against every possible ssl error code?